# Index out of range in a method of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm using Python and i have a problem in one code that consists of setting some operators, you can see the code bellow, i'm facing a problem in one method of the class which is `qrelay`as you can see in the code, and i am getting an error excatly in this part `for i in range(0,n-1):op = self.trans(op, self.bh[i], self.ah[i+1], self.bph[i], self.aph[i+1], B)
op = self.trans(op, self.bv[i], self.av[i+1], self.bpv[i], self.apv[i+1], B)`, you can see it properly in the code bellow . i don't know why but i get an `IndexError: list index out of range`even though it seems everything fine to me

```py
import numpy as np
from sympy import *


class Qrely:
    def __init__(self,ah=(),bh=(),av=(),bv=(),aph=(),bph=(), apv=(),bpv=()):
        self.ah=ah
        self.bh=bh
        self.av=av
        self.bv=bv
        self.aph=aph
        self.bph=bph
        self.apv=apv
        self.apv=bpv


    def trans(self, op, a, b, ap, bp, B):
        p =B * [ap, bp]
        op = op.subs(a, p[0])
        op = op.subs(b, p[1])
        return op

    def rotatmatrix(self, theta):
        c = np.cos(theta)
        s = np.sin(theta)

        return np.matrix([[c, s], [-s, c]])

    def qrelay_op(self,n, phi, alpha, delta):
        self.ah = [symbols('a_H1{:d}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,n)]
        self.bh = [symbols('b_H1{:d}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,n)]
        self.av = [symbols('a_V1{:d}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,n)]
        self.bv = [symbols('b_V1{:d}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,n)]

        print(self.ah, self.bh, self.av, self.bv)
        print(self.ah[1])
        op = 0

        for i in range(0,n-1):
            op += phi[i] * (self.ah[i]*self.bh[i] + self.av[i]*self.bv[i])

        B = 1/sqrt(2)*np.array([[1, 1],[-1, 1]])

        self.aph = [symbols("a'_H1{:d}".format(i)) for i in range(1,n)]
        self.bph = [symbols("b'_H1{:d}".format(i)) for i in range(1,n)]
        self.apv = [symbols("a'_V1{:d}".format(i)) for i in range(1,n)]
        self.bpv = [symbols("b'_V1{:d}".format(i)) for i in range(1,n)]

        print(self.aph, self.bph, self.apv, self.bpv)

        for i in range(0,n-1):
            op = self.trans(op, self.bh[i], self.ah[i+1], self.bph[i], self.aph[i+1], B)
            op = self.trans(op, self.bv[i], self.av[i+1], self.bpv[i], self.apv[i+1], B)

        op = self.trans(op, self.ah[0], self.av[0], self.aph[0], self.apv[0], self.rotatmatrix(alpha))
        op = self.trans(op, self.bh[n-1], self.bv[n-1], self.bph[n-1], self.bpv[n-1], self.rotatmatrix(delta))

        syms = Qrely(self.ah, self.bh, self.av, self.bv, self.aph, self.bph, self.apv, self.bpv)

        return syms, op
```

when i want to test it by calling the class and the `qrelay_op`by typing `A=Qrely()  print(A.qrelay_op(3,np.array([10,20,10]),10,20))` i get this error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range` and the error according to the traceback is in: 

line 58, in qrelay_op op=self.trans(op,self.bh[i],self.ah[i+1],self.bph[i],self.aph[i+1], B)
```

Comment: Please reformat the question properly

Comment: from Radin GeekGaming:It would be better if you state your programming language somewhere in the beginning. But at the bottom, I can see the tags or your interests (I'm not exactly sure which one) saying Python.

Answer (score 1):

Since `self.aph` and `self.bph` are always the same length, when you try and do `self.bph[i], self.aph[i+1]` you're accessing the last item in the `self.bph` list and trying to access an item *past* the last item in `self.aph`.

Comment: but i have to because in this line `op = self.trans(op, self.bh[i], self.ah[i+1], self.bph[i], self.aph[i+1], B)`i'm calling the trans method which is going to substitute in this case `self.bh[i]`will be substituted with `self.bph[i]` and `self.ah[i+1]`by  `self.aph[i+1]`

Comment: but `self.aph[i+1]` doesn't exist.